# An efficient algorithm to group a list of tuples

Tags: java, algorithm

I would like to develop an efficient algorithm which will group a list of tuples, as presented below:

```
public class Tuple<T, R> {

    private final T left;
    private final R right;

    public Tuple(T left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public T getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public R getRight() {
        return right;
    }
}
```

And return them grouped, based on equality of 'left' fields or 'right' fields. An output can be a list of groups as specified below:

```
public class Group<L, R> extends Tuple<List<L>, List<R>> {

    public Group(List<L> left, List<R> right) {
        super(left, right);
    }
}
```

How can I do this efficiently? Is there a way to parallelise such algorithm using some intermediate concurrent data structures?

Example input: `Tuple(4,C),Tuple(1,A),Tuple(2,B),Tuple(3,B),Tuple(3,A), Tuple(5,C), Tuple(6,D)`
Expected output: `Group((1,2,3),(A,B)), Group((4,5),(C)), Group((6),(D))`

Many thanks for help in advance. Any pseudo code will be appreciated.

Comment: So haven't tried anything on your own? And we have to set up the testdata ourselves, everybody again and again? [mcve] please.

Comment: I suggest using a `Set`, not `List` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to build a  [graph with strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component). 
The graph can be represented in the following way:

1. Nodes: each value (left or right) from each tupple is a node. In your case you will have the following nodes: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, A, B, C, D
2. Edges: the tupples themselves. In your case you will have the following edges: (1,A), (2,B), (3,A), (3,B), (4,C), (5,C), (6,D).

Because your graph is [Undirected Graph](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41graph/), each group will be represented as a strongly connected component and to find those groups you can simply run [BFS Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).